# cyber pet switch statements, adding to an int dont know why c++

Tags: c++

I've been working on this cyber pet.
I'm trying to update the sleep and hunger values and be able to output the status of them.

I can update the hunger and the sleep, but if i try to show the status it updates hunger and sleep once, then if i show status again it will show the new value without updating it again.

just wondering if anyone can shed some light on this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int hunger = 1;
int sleepy = 1;
int x = 0;

int main()
{
    string feed(int); //to feed pet
    string sleep(int); //to rest pet
    string displyFeed(int);
    string displySleep(int);

    while (x != 4)
    {
        cout << "1 to feed, 2 to nap, 3 state, 4 quit" << endl;

        cin >> x;

        string feed2 = feed(hunger);
        string sleep2 = sleep(sleepy);
        string disply1 = displyFeed(hunger);
        string disply2 = displySleep(sleepy);

        switch (x)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "pet is" << feed2 << endl;
            hunger++;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "pet is" << sleep2 << endl;
            sleepy++;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "pet is" << disply1 << endl;
            cout << "pet is" << disply2 << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        }
    }
}

string feed(int hunger2)
{
    switch (hunger2)
    {
    case 0:
        return "DEAD";
        break;
    case 1:
        return "very hungry.... almost DEAD";
        break;
    case 2:
        return "hungry";
        break;
    case 3:
        return "fed";
        break;
    case 4:
        return "full";
        break;
    }
}

string sleep(int sleep2)
{
    switch (sleep2)
    {
    case 0:
        return "ALSEEP";
        break;
    case 1:
        return "very sleepy.... almost ASLEEP";
        break;
    case 2:
        return "sleepy";
        break;
    case 3:
        return "rested";
        break;
    case 4:
        return "well rested";
        break;
    }
}

string displyFeed(int hunger3)
{
    switch (hunger3) {
    case 0:
        return "DEAD";
        break;
    case 1:
        return "Very hungry";
        break;
    case 2:
        return "hungry";
        break;
    case 3:
        return "well fed";
        break;
    case 4:
        return "full";
        break;
    }
}

string displySleep(int sleep3)
{
    switch (sleep3) {
    case 0:
        return "ASLEEP";
        break;
    case 1:
        return "Very sleepy";
        break;
    case 2:
        return "sleepy";
        break;
    case 3:
        return "rested";
        break;
    case 4:
        return "well rested";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should move the function declarations out of `main` function. The question is unclear for me. Please provide a [mcve] with input data, expected output and actual output.

Comment: You don't need to give unique names to your functions' parameters.

Comment: The lack of a return value for arguments greater than 4 in your functions cause undefined behaviour if you feed or sleep four times.